# Using header(), does the header get sent instantly, or after the full script has run?

Tags: php, http, header

I'm working with an external service that polls data from my app. A requirement of this external service is that I have to let it know that its request was successful after a maximum of 10 seconds. The problem is that the script this service connects to might take more than 10 seconds to execute.

My question is: When I sent the headers via *header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK', true, 200);*, will the external service receive this response immediately, or only after my script has executed completely? Example:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK', true, 200);
some_function_that_takes_20_seconds()
```

Will the response header be sent immediately or only after 20 seconds?

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself and see?

Comment: I have done some tests, and they indicate that the headers do get sent instantly. However I am not 100% sure and I don't want to rely on my subpar testing skills. Searching the docs hasn't provided any results hence I am hoping that the community can provide a clear answer.

Comment: Put one header at the top and one at the bottom, do a time test

Comment: Could you recommend a debugging tool to capture the timestamps of the headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly send the header by calling `flush()` immediately after your `header()` call, otherwise I believe no headers are sent until the output buffer is flushed, or your script finishes - whichever comes first.

Comment: Yes, that seems to solve the problem. However, I noticed it only works locally, and not on my server. Any idea what might be causing that behavior? Edit: Never mind, seems to be a server configuration issue, probably not something for a SO comment. ;) Thanks!

Comment: This is how I used ob_flush to immediately output the header before the scrip had finished.
       ' ob_start();'
        '//do some stuff  '      

 header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
 header("Content-Type: application/json");
 header("Content-Length: " .strlen($responseMessage));
 ob_end_clean();  //Prevents all other echo text being sent
 echo $responseMessage;
 ob_flush(); //Pushes the response out without waiting for the script to end.
        flush();
        //Header sent and now do other stuff

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you have resolved your problem but try

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK', true, 200);
flush();
```